# Datetime issues with Mongo and C#

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-4.0, mongodb

I'm having an issue with saving and retrieving dates with Mongo using the c# driver. For some reason it it's truncating the ticks.

When I store this:

```
DateTime -> 5/17/2011 7:59:13 PM 
Ticks -> 634412591533741650
```

I get this back:

```
DateTime -> 5/17/2011 7:59:13 PM 
Ticks -> 634412591533740000
```

So if I try to do:

```
serverDateTime == mongoDateTime
```

It always fails. Anyway around this?

Comment: If you don't care about milliseconds precistion in your comparison, instead of `serverDateTime == mongoDateTime` you could do `Math.Abs((serverDateTime  - mongoDateTime).TotalMilliseconds < 1000`

Comment: That's good enough but way too verbose to have to do everywhere. I suppose I could do it as an extension method. Any idea why that happens though?

Comment: @Bala R 1 tick = 1 ten-millionth of a second, so I think you mean if *all* you care about is milliseconds. e.g. `Math.Abs((serverDateTime - mongoDateTime).TotalMilliseconds) < 1`.

Comment: @Conrad my logic was to ignore any diff under a second. I didn't consider the ticks, just the fact that 1000ms = 1s.

Comment: @Bala R. Oh I see. I guess I had ticks in my head from the question

Comment: @Micah I have no clue why there is truncation/loss of precision.

Comment: Not sure if you care but you'd get the same problem with SQL Server DateTime as well (But not with DateTime2).

Comment: As an added irritation the same problem exists even if you are using the `BsonDocument` class directly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is that the BSON DateTime format stores values with less precision than a .NET DateTime value, so when you read it back from the database the value has been truncated.

If your DateTime value is a property of a C# class you are serializing you can ask the serializer to serialize the DateTime value as an embedded document containing both the BSON DateTime value (truncated) and the original .NET DateTime value (stored as Ticks). In that case the value will not be truncated when deserialized.

For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public ObjectId Id;
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Document)]
    public DateTime MyDateTime;
}
```

You can also use a BsonRepresentation of Int64 or String and not lose precision, but then the stored document *only* has Ticks or a string representation and no BSON DateTime, which makes it hard to do DateTime related queries.

You'll also want to keep in mind that DateTime values are stored in UTC in the database. The best practice is to always use UTC values for storage and only use local times when displaying them to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm going to store it as a datetime but use @Bala R's extension method for comparison.

Comment: This attribute usage throws exception "A serialization options attribute of type BsonRepresentationAttribute cannot be applied ..." for me, but `[BsonDateTimeOptions(Representation = BsonType.Document)]` works fine

Answer (score 3):

Here's an extension you could use :)

```
public static class MongoDateComparison
{
    private static int precisionInMilliseconds = 1000;
    public static bool  MongoEquals(this DateTime dateTime, DateTime mongoDateTime)
    {
        return Math.Abs((dateTime - mongoDateTime).TotalMilliseconds) < precisionInMilliseconds;
    }
}
```