# How to find newest document in Mongo Collection (C#)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I find the most recent document in a MongoCollection? Currently I'm doing the following, but it seems to be returning the same value regardless:

```
_collection.FindAllAs<Game>().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("When")).FirstOrDefault<Game>();
```

The documents are structured in pseudocode as follows:

```
Game
{
    DateTime When;
    List<Score> Scores;
    ...other variables...
}
```

The games are always stored sequentially via `Update.PushWrapped<Score>(Score s)`

How could I improve this?

Comment: Could you post the structure of your document?  Also, what type is "When" in C# and in the database?  I also assume there is more than 1 document in the collection and that there are documents in the collection newer than the document you continue to receive.

Comment: @CraigWilson Sorry. "When" is a DateTime object and is serialized as such. There are multiple documents. I have updated the original question.

Comment: Can you issue the query from the shell?  Also, do an explain?  e.g. db.(collectionname).find().sort({"When": -1});  Also, add explain to the end:  db.(collectionname).find().sort({"When": -1}).explain();

Comment: @CraigWilson I think it actually might be due to the lack of precision when storing DateTime objects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036433/datetime-issues-with-mongo-and-c-sharp It appears to work now that I force larger time differences between submissions. If I then added `(...).AsQueryable<Score>()` I would preventing the copying of the entire list into memory, correct?

Comment: Sort of.  Using linq would be a little different:  var game = _collection.AsQueryable<Game>().OrderByDescending(x => x.When).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @CraigWilson I mean for the list contained within the game that I select. I do not want to copy the entire list of scores because that could be quite large. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a collection that stores the last inserted _id value of your collections and query for this value when you need to get the newest document.

As I said, that is one possible solution, and I'm sure that it will works, but maybe is not the best solution, it depends on your documents structure, etc.

I use this solution to do autoinc fields.