# Convert MongoDB BsonTimestamp to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, mongodb-csharp-2.0

What is the proper way to convert a BsonTimestamp field to a C# DateTime type?

This is for data in MongoDB's oplog collection and using the MongoDB C# driver.

Comment: Looks like that can help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036433/datetime-issues-with-mongo-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB's `Timestamp` is the elapsed seconds since the Unix epoch (1970/1/1).
Therefore, the conversion from `Timestamp` to `DateTime` is like this:

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(bsonTimestamp.Timestamp);
```

In terms of `Value` / `Timestamp` properties, they are implmented in both constructors of  `BsonTimestamp` in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver.

Constructor 1:

```
public BsonTimestamp(long value)
{
    _value = value;
}
```

Constructor 2:

```
public BsonTimestamp(int timestamp, int increment)
{
    _value = (long)(((ulong)(uint)timestamp << 32) | (ulong)(uint)increment);
}
```

Property:

```
public long Value
{
    get { return _value; }
}

public int Timestamp
{
    get { return (int)(_value >> 32); }
}
```

Since you are getting the timestamp records from oplog, their format would be like this:

```
Timestamp(1406171938, 1)
```

AS the second number (`increment`) is an ordinal number to make the `Timestamp` unique according to [MongoDB reference](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-timestamp), you should use `Timestamp` property I think.

Comment: I worked up something similar but used bsonTimestamp.Timestamp instead of bsontTimestamp.Value. Do you know whether to prefer one over the other? If not, I can give it a spin tomorrow.

Comment: @GaTechThomas I mistook you are getting records from oplog then so I updated my answer. I think you might want to use `Timestamp` property.

Comment: Fantastic info. Above and beyond. All answers should be written this way.

Comment: There's a great point added as a separate answer regarding time zone. It would be helpful to others if your answer were updated in that regard. Here's the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44140244/284598

Answer (score 4):

I believe the accepted answer in slightly off as [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) must be in UTC format.

```
var unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

From BsonTimestamp to DateTime

```
var target = unixEpoch.AddSeconds(bsonTimestamp.Timestamp - 18000);
```

From DateTime to BsonTimestamp

```
var target = DateTime.UtcNow;
var diff = target.ToUniversalTime() - unixEpoch;
var seconds = (diff.TotalMilliseconds + 18000000) / 1000;
var ts = new BsonTimestamp((int)seconds, 1);
```

You need to use `target.ToUniversalTime()` to ensure the incoming parameter, if any, is always positioned for UTC.

Comment: Great point! Fortunately our servers are on UTC, but this could lead to some local dev/test issues.

Comment: I think DateTime instance would be created correctly regardless of server configuration, you just have to indicate DateTimeKind.Utc.

Comment: So the "18000" magic number is just the time zone (UTC-5) offset?

Comment: I think it is a "magic number", but I don't think it has anything to do with your timezone offset.  In the above example when converting BsonTimestamp to DateTime, the value you get out of that is UTC.

Comment: It looks to me there is no reason for "18000". For me it works only if I omit it.

Comment: Can you please explain the value of adding the 18000 seconds when going from  DateTime to BsonTimestamp and then subtracting it when going from BsonTimestamp to DateTime? Why not just save the values with no such adjustment?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a BSON document:

```
DateTime dateTime = doc["BSONdateTime"].AsDateTime;
```

where "dateTime" is the variable you want to set, "doc" is the BSON document you extracted from MongoDB, and "BSONdateTime" is the key that you want to extract the date and time from.

I haven't tried this myself, but I was able to extract string values from BSON documents in MongoDB using:

```
string name = doc["name"].AsString;
```

I would also recommend you look into POCO, as this makes type conversion a lot easier and less boilerplate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: From C# view I would recommend to use BsonDateTime.ToUniversalTime() or ToLocalTime(), depending on what you require.